# eval() works in one function but not in other

Tags: javascript

I am implementing Highcharts using AJAX and Local Storage for Phonegap. I have 2 functions almost the same code but **eval()** works in one function only.

It works in the below function

```
var teamactivitygameGraph = window.localStorage.getItem("teamactivitygameGraph");
AGW = JSON.parse(teamactivitygameGraph);
var Gdata = AGW.data;

//alert(Gdata);

json = "[" + Gdata  + "]";

//alert(json);
//console.info(json);
var myData = eval(json);

myData.push({
    name: 'yellowline',
    visible: false,
    showInLegend: false,
    data: yellowLineData
});

alert('Weekly: '+myData);
```

On Alert it outputs the following, which is great:

```
Weekly: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

In the below function it gives in an error in chrome n firefox debug Consoler.**anonymous function** on eval()

```
var teamdayactivitygameGraph = window.localStorage.getItem("teamdayactivitygameGraph");
AGD = JSON.parse(teamdayactivitygameGraph);
var Gdata = AGD.data;

var json = "[" + Gdata  + "]";

//alert(json);
//console.info(json);
var myData = eval(json);

myData.push({
    name: 'yellowline',
    visible: false,
    showInLegend: false,
    data: yellowLineData
});

alert('Daily: '+myData);
```

this function doesn't alert anything.

Any help will be great! thanks in advance

Comment: Offtopic: Eval should only be used when there is no reasonable alternative. As far as I can tell, there are a few alternatives for what you are doing :)

Comment: It will be good if you can share them!

Comment: Why do you use `eval()` here at all? `JSON.parse()` should do the trick as well.

Comment: @Sirko it is not doing the trick as when I put the variable **Gdata** inside the Highcharts code. It displays a blank series.

Comment: @colourtheweb I meant you to change  `var myData = eval(json);` to ` var myData = JSON.parse(json);`. As it looks `Gdata` is just a string.

Comment: @Sirko Just tried JSON.parse and I get the following **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n**

Comment: @colourtheweb Please add the content of `Gdata` it seems it may not be valid.

Comment: @Sirko This is what it returns and I checked yes **Gdata** is returning string.=>> **{name: "Joe",stack: "joe@example.com",data: [[Date.parse('10/14/2013 UTC'), 8.9905667952813 ][Date.parse('10/15/2013 UTC'), null ][Date.parse('10/16/2013 UTC'), null ][Date.parse('10/17/2013 UTC'), null ][Date.parse('10/18/2013 UTC'), null ][Date.parse('10/19/2013 UTC'), null ][Date.parse('10/20/2013 UTC'), null ]]},{name: "Mark",stack: "mark@example.com",data: []}}**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39407/discussion-between-sirko-and-colourtheweb)

Comment: Every time someone uses `eval()`, a puppy is heartlessly dropped off a cliff somewhere.